# Error when starting fsi

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have installed F# using Visual Studio Community Edition and I also installed the [Visual F# 4.0 Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48179)

When I run fsi from a command prompt an exception is thrown

[image]

I also tried adding the F# to the path, but that did not solve the problem. What else should I do?

**Edit:**

If I run fsi directly from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0 it works.

Comment: so this solves your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my problem fixed with using the [F# forum on google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fsharp-opensource/q-HhOSWvBbc).

But for the reference, here's the solution.

After running *where fsi* I had this output:

```
λ where fsi
C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin\fsi.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\Fsi.exe
```

For some reason fsi from dotnet core is not working. I changed the order in my system path so that the F# Tools came before dotnet core and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the Visual F# 4.0 tools, then start Visual Studio and check if the F# interactive window works there. This could be something specific to your machine or a mismatch between VS2015 and the F# Tools. Specifically VS2015 Update 1 had some wrong redirects. And the F# there is higher than F# 4.0 Tools. Can you confirm your VS2015 version?

Btw, fsi.exe should be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0`

and the version is `Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 14.0.23413.0`

Comment: I just uninstalled everything VS and F# related... I reinstalled VS2015 Update 2 and I have the same error. I have this error in two different computers

Comment: Can you install VS2015 RTM (not Update1 or Update2)? I assume you haven't installed F# Tools. When does this error occur? When you start VS? (Un)fortunately I don't have Update2 installed. I recall that I had to go in and fix devenv.exe.config for VS after Update 1. Are you installing onto a stock PC or is this some special setup? I don't remember bumpin into System.ConsolePal

Comment: I had Update1 before. I haven't installed F# Tools. The error occurs when I open a console and try to run fsi. On VS everything works great

Comment: so... 1. in VS F# interactive window works, 2. if you double-click fsi.exe it works, 3. if you start cmd.exe and type fsi.exe into it you get the error. Is that a good summary? My guess would be a non-standard setup (MacOS or Linux) or something strange in your Path.

Comment: That's it. But I'm running everything on Windows 10.

Comment: Looking at the error message though it indicates some sort of version mismatch, maybe in .NET. And just maybe it shows up when using cmd. xe I'm not a big fan of randomly trying stuff, but the only other thing I can come up with is for you to install the windows 8 SDK: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk and hopefully someone can give a better answer.

Comment: I did that as well :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109166/discussion-between-s952163-and-vintem).

Comment: Problem solved. I answered my own question. But thanks for your help.